# `longjmp` into a terminated function

Tags: c, linux

Exercise 6.2 in "The Linux Programming Interface" by Michael Kerrisk asks:

> Write a program to see what happens if we try to `longjmp()` into a function that has already terminated.

I was thinking that this program ought do the trick:

```c
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static jmp_buf env;

void foo (void);
void bar (void);
void baz (void);

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    foo();
    bar();

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void
foo (void)
{
    printf("foo start\n");

    switch (setjmp(env)) {
    case 0:
        printf("foo branch 0\n");
        break;
    case 1:
        printf("foo branch 1\n");
        break;
    }

    printf("foo end\n");
    return;
}

void
bar (void)
{
    printf("bar start\n");

    baz();

    printf("bar end\n");
    return;
}

void
baz (void)
{
    printf("baz start\n");

    longjmp(env, 1);

    printf("baz end\n");
    return;
}
```

Instead, this prints:

```bash
$ ./setjmp
foo start
foo branch 0
foo end
bar start
baz start
foo branch 1
foo end
```

That is, the behaviour I would have expected if `foo` had not terminated. Why is that? How can I modify my program to achieve a `longjmp` into a terminated function?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Your task was to write a program to see what happens. You did. You saw what happens. So what's the problem?

Comment: I have a feeling Mr. Kerrisk was referring to the fact that the values of local variables in foo() may have been scribbled over by other functions using the same stack space after foo()'s initial termination.  The _control flow_ in foo() is still the same when you `longjmp()` back into it.

Comment: Maybe this will help: what do you think happens if the invocation to `foo` passes in a whole pile of arguments, and `foo` initializes a whole pile of local variables, and then prints out those locals and formals after the jump?

Comment: More generally: The exercise "try this undefined behaviour and see what happens" is somewhat bogus. The behaviour in question is *undefined*, and that means literally anything can happen. You observed *something* happening; "something" is a subset of "anything".

Comment: Another interesting question is where the flow of control resumes after `foo` terminates for the second time.  The first time it terminates, the stack is set up properly to return to `foo`'s caller.  That is probably not the case after `foo` terminates for the second time... undefined behavior indeed.

Comment: Why would anyone do such a thing?  It's insane.

Comment: @EricLippert I was trying to make this program crash horribly, and instead got a working program. My understanding was that the stack pointer in `env` would be pointing to some function other than `foo` when resuming execution, instead it looked like everything was normal. But I get your point about undefined behaviour.

Comment: @ChrisRice I see. I was actually trying to put another stack frame where `foo` was, so that execution resumed somewhere else and my program would crash. There's an example about variable clobbering in the book, but I was hoping I could "smash the stack".

Comment: @MartinJames Yes, it is. But "semel in anno licet insanire", right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setjmp.h#Cooperative_multitasking). Take with a grain of salt.

> **Jumping to a function that has already terminated by return or longjmp
>   is undefined.[6] However, most implementations of longjmp do not
>   specifically destroy local variables when performing the jump.** Since
>   the context survives until its local variables are erased, it could
>   actually be restored by setjmp.

Luckily, they do quote the (albeit old) standard.

§7.13.2.1/2

> The longjmp function restores the environment saved by the most recent
>   invocation of the setjmp macro in the same invocation of the program
>   with the corresponding jmp_buf argument. If there has been no such
>   invocation, **or if the function containing the invocation of the setjmp
>   macro has terminated execution<sup>211)</sup> in the interim**, or if the
>   invocation of the setjmp macro was within the scope of an identifier
>   with variably modified type and execution has left that scope in the
>   interim, **the behavior is undefined.**
>
> 211) For example, by executing a return statement or because another
>   longjmp call has caused a transfer to a setjmp invocation in a
>   function earlier in the set of nested calls.

Comment: Ah, yes, that's the behaviour I'm witnessing. Thank you for quoting the standard!